# the function of 'bounding_boxes' and 'min_object_covered' in tf.image.sample_distorted_bounding_box?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

How parameters 'bounding_boxes' and 'min_object_covered' control the generation of a single randomly distorted bounding box for an image in tf.image.sample_distorted_bounding_box?

I have read the [function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/sample_distorted_bounding_box) in tensorflow api, but I still can not understand the proplem. Maybe I need a intuitive example.